# Jenkins Trend Graph Images Broken

Tags: jenkins, graph, trend

For both Pylint(warnings plugin) and Corbertura Code Coverage trend graphs do not display on main project page and on drilldown. One build displays graphs fine, as soon as a second build is added the image does not resolve. Junit graph is displaying fine. The console reports no errors and the data is accurate in the tables. Just graphs are broken.